# how to beautify validations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple scaffold rails application that is doing validataes_presence_of.

The validation is making each textfield bordered.  I just want the error messages to be displayed on top.

How can I make these type of changes or color changes to the validation

Answer (score 4):

Rails applications store their [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) in `[application_root]/public/stylesheets`.  A new rails app will have a file called `default.css` in this directory.  This file contains the following:

```
#errorExplanation {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#errorExplanation h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: -7px;
  background-color: #c00;
  color: #fff;
}

#errorExplanation p {
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#errorExplanation ul li {
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style: square;
}
```

If you play about with the values of some of the parameters here - in particular `border` - you might find something that looks more to your taste.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view) about validation errors?

Comment: link doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at [Formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic). Easy to setup, works great with scaffold-type apps and has some nice clean HTML and CSS.