# Rails / Devise custom error messages for sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a website that uses Devise for authentication.

I want to show different error messages for users for different cases:

1. email & password don't match
2. email not found in database

Can anyone help me to understand what devise methods I should override, and how?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125349/how-do-you-edit-devise-error-messages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you edit Devise error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125349/how-do-you-edit-devise-error-messages)